# How to replace smaller dataframe in a larger dataframe using placeholders?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on report Generation using Dataframes in Pandas. The report will eventually be very huge spanning multiple sheets in Microsoft Excel.

I plan to populate smaller chunks of dataframe ( marked blue) and populate it the final dataframe. I plan to use placeholder in the final dataframe.

Any idea how to do it ?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how you fill in values in specific ranges of your dataframe? - As in, filling in rows 10-20 and columns 5-15 with the value 6.

Comment: Not really, I will have placeholder #placeholder1# in the final df. I will replace the smaller df starting from that cell

Comment: So, you just want the smaller df to equal a section of the larger dataframe? As in `df_smaller = df_larger.iloc[10:20, 5:15]`

Comment: That's right, i was wondering if  i could avoid using the index to place the smaller df in the final larger df. I would like to use the placeholder as a means to place a smaller section of the df in the final df